# com.typesafe.scala-logging#scala-logging-slf4j_2.12;2.1.2: not found

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

Why do I get these `UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES` errors

My build.sbt has the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
....
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2"
)
```

I also tried

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2"
```

to see if that would make a difference. With `%%` and `%` after group id. And I tried with and without

```
resolvers += "slf4j repo" at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.scala-logging/scala-logging-slf4j",
```

What am I missing, what am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Apparently the problem is that this library is not meant for my version of Scala :(

Comment: Are there any reasons why you want to use library that was obsolete for 6 years if you want to update to I assume newer version of Scala?

Comment: No reason, I just didn't know it was obsolete. I am very new to Scala. Was trying to mimic what other project was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a while scala-logging assumes that you always want to use [slf4j](https://github.com/lightbend/scala-logging#prerequisites) - so just remove that dependency and fetch only

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.2"
```

it will work for Scala 2.11, 2.12 and 2.13